Происхождение слов «коучер», «акушерка», «кучер»
Все чаще слышу слово «коучер». Существуют пространные толкования этого новомодного термина: https://wikigrowth.com/razvitie/coacher/
Можно ли доказать, что корень этого слова заимствуется русским языком не впервые и к предыдущим случаям следует относить наименования таких профессий, как «акушерка» и «кучер».

нет, это совершенно разные слова: https://www.etymonline.com/word/accoucheur#etymonline_v_124 https://www.etymonline.com/word/coaching#etymonline_v_53399 . Акушер - это скорее от кушетка от coucher(фр) «спать, лежать», а коуч родственное с кучер и крытая телега, которая была изобретена в Венгрии в 15 веке - карета, коч, коуч и тп.  kocsi (szekér)

https://pashyrey.livejournal.com/670510.html - коучер это инструктор у кучеров.) тот кто учил кучера управлять повозкой.

Уважаемый Буратино, все совпадения в звучании слов «акушерка» и «кушетка» - чисто случайны. На роль Сочувствующего коучера для роженицы «кушетка» явно не годится.
«Женщины в родах очень уязвимы. Они многого не знают, и я стараюсь всегда им все рассказать, объяснить, что происходит прямо сейчас и что их будет ждать дальше...» https://vk.com/@melfmru-rabota-v-rodilnom-eto-sokovyzhimalka-anonimnyi-monolog-akush

Не понял половину того, что вы хотели сказать). Я в начале не очень точно написал, слова акушерка и кучер-коучер - не однокоренные, а слова кучер и коучер - однокоренные.
